# Can I start with Plants vs. Zombies Game of the Year edition?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I've never played any Plants vs. Zombies games. The PopCap site says this on their: [Plants vs. Zombies page](http://www.popcap.com/games/plants-vs-zombies/pc):

> Get ready to soil your plants! Again! PopCap's fun-dead game of the year is updated and expanded with 20 new achievements and the interactive Zombatar™. Make your very own zombie, then watch it come to "life" in your game!
>
> Stop 26 types of zombies dead in their tracks with your arsenal of 49 zombie-zapping plants! Battle through 50 Adventure levels, 20 Mini-Games, plus Puzzle and Survival modes. Or dig into the zombie-free Zen Garden. The fun never dies!

Looks like this is a sequel. Is there another version that I should get to get into the series? Or is this the original, with extra features?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, it's not - it's the same game, with a few bits added on.

Comment: Yep. Nothing special.

Comment: If you have it through Steam, it even automatically upgraded when the GotY edition came out.

Answer (score 4):

It's the original with a few extra features. Try the demo and see if you like it. :)